# Spark - Permissive mode with JSON file moves all records to corrupt column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying ingest a JSON file using spark. I am applying schema manually to create Dataframe. the problem is even for a single record of schema is not matching it moves whole file (all the records) to corrupt column?

**Data**

```
[{
  "RecordNumber": 2,
  "Zipcode": 704,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "PASEO COSTA DEL SUR",
  "State": "PR"
},
{
  "RecordNumber": 10,
  "Zipcode": 709,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "BDA SAN LUIS",
  "State": "PR"
},{
  "Zipcode": "709aa",
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "BDA SAN LUIS",
  "State": "PR"
}]
```

**Code**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes._
 val s = StructType(StructField("City",StringType,true) ::
 StructField("RecordNumber",LongType,true) ::
 StructField("State",StringType,true) ::
 StructField("ZipCodeType",StringType,true) ::
 StructField("Zipcode",LongType,true) ::
 StructField("corrupted_record",StringType,true) ::
 Nil)
 val df2=spark.read.
option("multiline","true").
option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").
option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "corrupted_record").
schema(s).
json("/tmp/test.json")
df2.show(false)
```

**Output**

```
scala> df2.filter($"corrupted_record".isNotNull).show(false)
+----+------------+-----+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|City|RecordNumber|State|ZipCodeType|Zipcode|corrupted_record                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+----+------------+-----+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|null|null        |null |null       |null   |[{
  "RecordNumber": 2,
  "Zipcode": 704,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "PASEO COSTA DEL SUR",
  "State": "PR"
},
{
  "RecordNumber": 10,
  "Zipcode": 709,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "BDA SAN LUIS",
  "State": "PR"
},{
  "Zipcode": "709aa",
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "BDA SAN LUIS",
  "State": "PR"
}]
```

**Question**
As only third record has Zipcode in `String` while I expect it to be `integer` (`"Zipcode": "709aa",`) shouldn't only third record go to `corrupted_record` column and others should be parsed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have only one record(that's because of multiline,true) which is corrupt so everything goes there.

Like it says in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) if you want spark to treat records separately you need to use [Json lines format](http://jsonlines.org/) which will also be more scalable for bigger files because spark will be able to distribute parsing in multiple executors.